# bootstrap modal dialog - opening from JavaScript

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm new to the web development world. Can anyone show an example on how to open a "bootstrap" (not ui-bootstrap) modal dialog from JavaScript without using jQuery?

There are quite a few examples on the web on how to use "ui-bootstrap" modals, but not the classic bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 0):

without jquery

```
        var dialog = document.getElementById("myDialog");
        dialog.className += " in";
        dialog.style.display = "block";
```

html for bootstrap v.3

```
<div id="myDialog" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">TITLE</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">BODY</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">FOOTER</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is:

```
document.getElementById("myDialog").modal("toggle");
```

Or with JQuery

```
$("#myDialog").modal("toggle");
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("myDialog").modal("toggle");` doesn't work for me.